# SQL Job for Sending Email Notifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How to create an SQL job that could send out email notifications (& NOT the email)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you better phrase your question?  Do you want to send e-mail, or not?  What is an e-mail notification if it is "NOT the e-mail"?

Comment: @Aaron: I wish to send an email before 'n' days from todays date. That could be done from SQL Job but not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Does [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) meet your needs or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Not sure whether this would be the solution. Thanks for the comment,though!